# When linked list element is created using calloc, how to delete element in the delete function without causing leaking issue?

Tags: c

My delete function can pass the test 1-5 shown in main() but can't pass test 6. The expected result is merely "abc". My result is not just "abc" but also with leaksing issue. Please refer to the attached image.

I think it is because for test 6 the node for 'g' is created explicitly using calloc which needs to be freed using free() method explicitly since the delete function I show here only delete and free memory of the corresponding node from the linkedlist. It doesn't interfere with the element passed. I try to rewrite the code many times but still can't solve the leaking issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1R0O.png)

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct linkedlistelement_s {
    char data;
    struct linkedlistelement_s* next;
};

typedef struct linkedlistelement_s LinkedListElement_t;

typedef struct {
    LinkedListElement_t* head;
    LinkedListElement_t* tail;
} LinkedList_t;

void addElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data);
LinkedListElement_t* findElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data);
void deleteElement(LinkedList_t* list, LinkedListElement_t* element);

int main()
{
  /* MAKE SURE TO CHECK THE LEAK USING BELOW COMMAND LINE IN LERMINAL
  cc -Wall -g -Werror filename.c -lmcheck
  valgrind ./filename.out */

  //TEST 1 - expected: ac
  // LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  // LinkedListElement_t* element;
  // addElement(&alist, 'a');
  // addElement(&alist, 'b');
  // addElement(&alist, 'c');
  // element = findElement(&alist, 'b');
  // deleteElement(&alist, element);
  // for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
  //     printf("%c", elem->data);
  // }
  // //Clean up
  // while (alist.head != NULL) {
  //     deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  // }


  // //TEST 2 - expected: correct
  // LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  // LinkedListElement_t* element;
  // addElement(&alist, 'a');
  // element = findElement(&alist, 'a');
  // deleteElement(&alist, element);
  // printf("%s", (alist.head == NULL && alist.tail == NULL) ? "Correct" : "Error");
  // //Clean up
  // while (alist.head != NULL) {
  //     deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  // }

  //
  // //TEST 3 - expected: abc
  // LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  // LinkedListElement_t* element;
  // addElement(&alist, 'a');
  // addElement(&alist, 'b');
  // addElement(&alist, 'c');
  // element = findElement(&alist, 'g');
  // deleteElement(&alist, element);
  // for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
  //     printf("%c", elem->data);
  // }
  // //Clean up
  // while (alist.head != NULL) {
  //     deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  // }

  //TEST 4 - expected: a
  // LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  // LinkedListElement_t* element;
  // addElement(&alist, 'a');
  // addElement(&alist, 'b');
  // element = findElement(&alist, 'b');
  // deleteElement(&alist, element);
  // for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
  //     printf("%c", elem->data);
  // }
  // //Clean up
  // while (alist.head != NULL) {
  //     deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  // }
  //
  // //TEST 5 - expected: b
  // LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  // LinkedListElement_t* element;
  // addElement(&alist, 'a');
  // addElement(&alist, 'b');
  // element = findElement(&alist, 'a');
  // deleteElement(&alist, element);
  // for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
  //     printf("%c", elem->data);
  // }
  // //Clean up
  // while (alist.head != NULL) {
  //     deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  // }

  // // //TEST 6 - expected: abc
  // LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  // LinkedListElement_t* element;
  // addElement(&alist, 'a');
  // addElement(&alist, 'b');
  // addElement(&alist, 'c');
  // element = (LinkedListElement_t*)calloc(sizeof(LinkedListElement_t), 1);
  // element->data = 'g';
  // deleteElement(&alist, element);
  // for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
  //     printf("%c", elem->data);
  // }
  // //Clean up
  // while (alist.head != NULL) {
  //     deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  // }
}

void addElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data)
{
    LinkedListElement_t* element = calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedListElement_t));
    element->data = data;
    element->next = NULL;

    if (list->tail == NULL) {
        list->head = element;
        list->tail = element;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = element;
        list->tail = element;
        element->next = NULL;
    }
}

LinkedListElement_t* findElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data)
{
    LinkedListElement_t* element = list->head;
    while (element != NULL) {
      if (element->data == data) {
        return element;
      }
      element = element->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}


void deleteElement(LinkedList_t *list, LinkedListElement_t *element)
{
    // No Element
    if (element == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // list is empty
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (list->head->data == element->data) {
        LinkedListElement_t * temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(temp);

        if (list->head == NULL) {
            list->tail = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        LinkedListElement_t *curr = list->head->next;
        LinkedListElement_t *prev = list->head;

        while (curr != NULL && curr->data != element->data) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        // element not found
        if (curr == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        if (curr->data == element->data) {
            prev->next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Never-mind -- you are searching for a `'g'` element which isn't found -- and you need to delete the memory you allocated for that node..In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` (`calloc` or `realloc`), it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Simply put `free(element);` as last statement in TEST 6. It has never been part of the list so it wont be delete by calling `deleteElement`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Is asking questions here in line with your course's policy? Either way, the setup seems odd to me. Yes, the error can be resolved by putting a `free` in TEST 6 which is where it naturally belongs as this function is also responsible for the allocation. However, this is adapting a test case to the program, while it should be the other way around. Moreover, a user (or test function) shouldn't be concerned with the inner workings of a data structure (e.g. alloc'ing a node); it should just be able to add and delete data (of type 'char' in this case).

Comment: the tests were provided by the server. I can not amend it. I have to do something in the delete function. I tried to put free(element) anywhere in delete function it didn't work. It took me nearly  a week to work on the delete function. This is the best I could get and it still doesn't pass given test 6

Comment: Then you will need to add a `free(element)` in `main()` after Test 6 completes, The problem being, `element = calloc(sizeof(LinkedListElement_t), 1);` (cast omitted) allocates a block of memory for a node and assigns the beginning address for that block to `element`. There is no corresponding `free(element);` so you leak that memory. (actually since it is allocated in `main()` it will be freed automatically on program exit -- but it is still reachable at the time of return from `main()` -- so `valgrind` will report it as such). ***RULE: If you allocate, validate and then free when done.***

Answer (score 1):

In Test 6, the problem is `element = calloc(sizeof(LinkedListElement_t), 1);` (unnecessary cast omitted) allocates a block of memory for a node and assigns the beginning address for that block to `element`. There is no corresponding `free(element);` so you leak that memory.

(actually since it is allocated in main() it will be freed automatically on program exit -- but it is still reachable at the time of return from `main()` -- so `valgrind` will report it as such).

To fix the problem, in (or after) the `//Clean up` part of your code, you need to add `free (element);`. That will correct the memory leak. (you should also only declare `LinkedList_t alist;` and `LinkedListElement_t* element;` once so all tests can be run in your program)

You have done your job in `deleteElement()` correctly (although it is much more complicated than need be, see: [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) and , e.g. `del_node()` in [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A))

To fix the issue, you need nothing more than:

```c
  LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  LinkedListElement_t* element;
  ...
  //TEST 6 - expected: abc
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  addElement(&alist, 'b');
  addElement(&alist, 'c');
  element = calloc(sizeof(LinkedListElement_t), 1);
  element->data = 'g';
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
      printf("%c", elem->data);
  }
  //Clean up
  free (element);
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }
```

Though you should allocate using the dereferenced pointer to set *type-size* and you must ***validate*** the allocation succeeds before using the block of memory, e.g.:

```c
  element = calloc(sizeof *element, 1);
  /* if you allocate, you must validate */
  if (!element) {
    perror ("calloc-element");
    return 1;
  }
```

Rearranging your declarations so there is only a single declaration for `alist` and `element` in your program, you could write your code to run all tests successfully as:

**linkedlist.h**

```c
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct linkedlistelement_s {
    char data;
    struct linkedlistelement_s* next;
};

typedef struct linkedlistelement_s LinkedListElement_t;

typedef struct {
    LinkedListElement_t* head;
    LinkedListElement_t* tail;
} LinkedList_t;

void addElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data);
LinkedListElement_t* findElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data);
void deleteElement(LinkedList_t* list, LinkedListElement_t* element);

#endif
```

(good job with your header-guards (`#ifndef ...`) to prevent multiple-inclusion of the header)

**linkedlist.c**

```c
#include "linkedlist.h"

void addElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data)
{
    LinkedListElement_t* element = calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedListElement_t));
    element->data = data;
    element->next = NULL;

    if (list->tail == NULL) {
        list->head = element;
        list->tail = element;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = element;
        list->tail = element;
        element->next = NULL;
    }
}

LinkedListElement_t* findElement(LinkedList_t* list, char data)
{
    LinkedListElement_t* element = list->head;
    while (element != NULL) {
      if (element->data == data) {
        return element;
      }
      element = element->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}


void deleteElement(LinkedList_t *list, LinkedListElement_t *element)
{
    // No Element
    if (element == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // list is empty
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (list->head->data == element->data) {
        LinkedListElement_t * temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(temp);

        if (list->head == NULL) {
            list->tail = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        LinkedListElement_t *curr = list->head->next;
        LinkedListElement_t *prev = list->head;

        while (curr != NULL && curr->data != element->data) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        // element not found
        if (curr == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        if (curr->data == element->data) {
            prev->next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.c**

With single declarations for `alist` and `element`, running all tests at once, and with included output of the test number before the test output and tidying up with the output of a `'\n'` between each test you would have:

```c
#include "linkedlist.h"

int main()
{
  /* MAKE SURE TO CHECK THE LEAK USING BELOW COMMAND LINE IN LERMINAL
   * cc -Wall -g -Werror filename.c -lmcheck
   * valgrind ./filename.out
   */

  LinkedList_t alist = {.head = NULL, .tail = NULL};
  LinkedListElement_t* element;
  
  //TEST 1 - expected: ac
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  addElement(&alist, 'b');
  addElement(&alist, 'c');
  element = findElement(&alist, 'b');
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  fputs ("TEST 1: ", stdout);
  for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
      printf("%c", elem->data);
  }
  //Clean up
  putchar ('\n');
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }

  //TEST 2 - expected: correct
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  element = findElement(&alist, 'a');
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  fputs ("TEST 2: ", stdout);
  printf("%s", (alist.head == NULL && alist.tail == NULL) ? "Correct" : "Error");
  //Clean up
  putchar ('\n');
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }
  
  //TEST 3 - expected: abc
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  addElement(&alist, 'b');
  addElement(&alist, 'c');
  element = findElement(&alist, 'g');
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  fputs ("TEST 3: ", stdout);
  for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
      printf("%c", elem->data);
  }
  //Clean up
  putchar ('\n');
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }

  // TEST 4 - expected: a
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  addElement(&alist, 'b');
  element = findElement(&alist, 'b');
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  fputs ("TEST 4: ", stdout);
  for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
      printf("%c", elem->data);
  }
  //Clean up
  putchar ('\n');
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }
  
  //TEST 5 - expected: b
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  addElement(&alist, 'b');
  element = findElement(&alist, 'a');
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  fputs ("TEST 5: ", stdout);
  for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
      printf("%c", elem->data);
  }
  //Clean up
  putchar ('\n');
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }

  //TEST 6 - expected: abc
  addElement(&alist, 'a');
  addElement(&alist, 'b');
  addElement(&alist, 'c');
  element = calloc(sizeof *element, 1);
  /* if you allocate, you must validate */
  if (!element) {
    perror ("calloc-element");
    return 1;
  }
  element->data = 'g';
  deleteElement(&alist, element);
  fputs ("TEST 6: ", stdout);
  for (LinkedListElement_t* elem=alist.head; elem != NULL; elem = elem->next) {
      printf("%c", elem->data);
  }
  //Clean up
  putchar ('\n');
  free (element);
  while (alist.head != NULL) {
      deleteElement(&alist, alist.head);
  }
}
```

**Example Compilation**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast linkedlist.c -o ./bin/main main.c
```

(I create a subdirectory `./bin` in my source code directory to prevent cluttering the source directory with executables. You can adjust the `-o name` as desired, and you can add `-Werror` to treat all warnings as errors -- good practice. Consider adding `-Wshadow` to catch shadowed variables as your programs get more involved)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/main
TEST 1: ac
TEST 2: Correct
TEST 3: abc
TEST 4: a
TEST 5: b
TEST 6: abc
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/main
==12743== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12743== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12743== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12743== Command: ./bin/main
==12743==
TEST 1: ac
TEST 2: Correct
TEST 3: abc
TEST 4: a
TEST 5: b
TEST 6: abc
==12743==
==12743== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12743==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12743==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 16 frees, 1,264 bytes allocated
==12743==
==12743== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12743==
==12743== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12743== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

There is no shortcut to prevent the leak without adding a `free(element);` -- regardless whether your professor wrote the tests or not. You can simply point out that fact to him (or her).

(often professors intentionally leave out code to see if the student can grasp and identify the needed omission)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your answer. For this question, everything else was defined by the lab server except for the add, find, delete function were written by us. We are not able to change the skeleton. We can't see the hidden tests until we submit the answer. I submitted the delete function multiple times to see the hidden tests at the cost of losing points and then I adjusted the code. For the moment, delete function looks good to me apart from passing the test 6 which is the tricky one. I want to figure out how to solve that as we will never have answer in the lab practice.

Comment: @Annie - you can add  `free (element);` at the end of `deleteElement()` before the function returns - FOR TEST 6 ONLY. That will solve your Test 6 problem, but will break the other tests where `element` was not an allocated node. Doing something to specialize one function for a single test would be a hack anyway. Like I said in the answer, you have done your job with `deleteElement()`. The allocation of `element` in Test 6 (the only Test where it is allocated), can only be cured by a `free (element);` in `main()`. Smack your prof for good measure...